# Can't disable ForeignKey referential integrity check in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with two entities, `Person` and `Code`. `Person` is referenced by `Code` twice, a `Person` can be either the `user` of the code or the `approver`.

What I want to achieve is the following:

- if the user provides an existing `Person.cusman`, no further action is needed.
- if the user provides an unknown `Person.cusman`, a helper code looks up other attributes of the `Person` (from an external database), and creates a new `Person` entity.

I have implemented a function triggered by `pre_save` signal, which creates the missing `Person` on the fly. It works fine as long as I use `python manage.py shell` to create a `Code` with nonexistent `Person`.

However, when I try to add a new `Code` using the admin form or a `CreateView` descendant I always get the following validation error on the HTML form:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

Obviously there's a validation happening between clicking on the Save button and the `Code.save()` method, but I can't figure out which is it. Can you help me which method should I override to accept invalid foreign keys until `pre_save` creates the referenced entity?

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    cusman = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0} ({1})'.format(self.name, self.cusman)


class Code(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        db_constraint=False)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='approves',
        db_constraint=False)
```

## signals.py

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Code)
def create_referenced_person(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    def create_person_if_doesnt_exist(cusman):
        try:
            Person = Person.objects.get(pk=cusman)
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            Person = Person()
            cr = CusmanResolver()
            Person_details = cr.get_person_details(cusman)
            Person.cusman = Person_details['cusman']
            Person.name = Person_details['name']
            Person.email = Person_details['email']
            Person.save()
    create_Person_if_doesnt_exist(instance.user_id)
    create_Person_if_doesnt_exist(instance.approver_id)
```

## views.py

```
class CodeAddForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Code
        fields = [
            'user',
            'approver',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'user': TextInput,
            'approver': TextInput
        }


class CodeAddView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'teladm/code_add.html'
    form_class = CodeAddForm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood one thing: You shouldn't use `TextField` to populate ForeignKey, because django foreign keys are populated using dropdown/radio button to refer to the `id` of the object in another model. The error you got means you provided wrong information that doesn't match any `id` in another model(`Person` in your case).

What you can do is: not using `ModelForm` but `Form`. You might have some extra work to do after you call `form.is_valid()`, but at least you could code up your logic however you want.

Comment: Actually I could just extend `ModelForm` with `CharField` and then override the `save()` method to implement the login as suggested. Thanks!